# In android how to find what /dev/input/event* is used for touchscreen using c function

Tags: android, c, linux, touch-event

I am trying to read touchscreen event, in my device /dev/input/event4 is used for touchscreen, while in some other phone, event7 is used for touchscreen.

I am looking for a c function that can help me
to find that touchscreen event.

Answer (score 4):

Each input event device has a corresponding entry in the `/sys/class/input/` pseudo-file hierarchy. (See [Linux Input Subsystem userspace API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/input_uapi.html) in the Linux kernel documentation for further details.)  For example, the name of the device corresponding to `event7` is in `/sys/class/input/event7/device/name`.

When you open the event character device (`/dev/input/event7`), you can use the EVIOCGBIT(type, bits) ioctl to check which kind of events the device can produce.  Touchpads will produce EV_ABS events ABS_X and ABS_Y, and EV_KEY event BTN_TOUCH.

Therefore, if you glob /dev/input/event*, open each device in turn, and check if they report the abovementioned three events, you are likely to find the device you look for.  For example:

```c
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <glob.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef  ULONG_BITS
#define  ULONG_BITS   (CHAR_BIT * sizeof (unsigned long))
#endif

static inline int  has_bit(const unsigned long  data[], const size_t  bit)
{
    return !!(data[bit / ULONG_BITS] & (1uL << (bit % ULONG_BITS)));
}

char *touchscreen_event_device(size_t skip)
{
    glob_t  files;
    int     result;

    result = glob("/dev/input/event*", 0, NULL, &files);
    if (result) {
        if (result == GLOB_NOSPACE) {
            errno = ENOMEM;
            return NULL;
        } else
        if (result == GLOB_NOMATCH) {
            errno = ENOENT;
            return NULL;
        } else {
            errno = EACCES;
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    for (size_t  i = 0;  i < files.gl_pathc;  i++) {
        int  fd = open(files.gl_pathv[i], O_RDONLY);
        if (fd != -1) {
            unsigned long  absbits[1 + ABS_MAX / ULONG_BITS] = { 0 };
            unsigned long  keybits[1 + KEY_MAX / ULONG_BITS] = { 0 };
            if (ioctl(fd, EVIOCGBIT(EV_ABS, ABS_MAX+1), &absbits) != -1 &&
                ioctl(fd, EVIOCGBIT(EV_KEY, KEY_MAX+1), &keybits) != -1) {
                if (has_bit(absbits, ABS_X) &&
                    has_bit(absbits, ABS_Y) &&
                    has_bit(keybits, BTN_TOUCH)) {
                    /* Device reports ABS_X, ABS_Y and BTN_TOUCH,
                       and therefore is a touchpad device. */
                    if (!skip) {
                        char *devpath = strdup(files.gl_pathv[i]);
                        close(fd);
                        globfree(&files);
                        if (!devpath)
                            errno = ENOMEM;
                        return devpath;
                    } else {
                        skip--;
                    }
                }
            }
            close(fd);
        }
    }
    globfree(&files);

    errno = ENOENT;
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t  i = 0;

    while (1) {
        char *devpath = touchscreen_event_device(i);
        if (!devpath) {
            if (i)
                break;
            fprintf(stderr, "No touchscreen input event devices found: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        printf("Found touchscreen input event device '%s'\n", devpath);
        free(devpath);
        i++;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile using e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 example.c -o example`, and run with root privileges, and it will list the paths to the input event devices it believes are touch screens.

Answer (score 0):

An answer for a complete code could be difficult because it's a long/heavy work.
I'll point you in right directions:

- read "*Input Event Codes*": https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/input/event-codes.html
- then you have to list all /dev/input/* files
- open each of them using "*fd = open("/dev/input/xxxxx", O_RDONLY);*"
- call "*ioctl(fd, EVIOCGBIT(**EV_REL**, sizeof(maskbit)), maskbit)*" (calling this changing "EV_REL" with others "Input Event Codes"
- analize "maskbit" by searching for some specific Values that only Touchscreen has

A possibile example could find here: https://android.googlesource.com/device/generic/brillo/+/d1917142dc905d808519023d80a664c066104600/examples/keyboard/keyboard_example.cpp in which the author looking for an Input that supports "KEY_B" Event Code.

Touchscreens should have:

- for **EV_ABS**:

  - ABS_X
  - ABS_Y
  - ABS_MT_SLOT
  - ABS_MT_POSITION_X
  - ABS_MT_POSITION_Y
  - ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID

If the Input has all these Bit it is a Touchscreen (reference: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt)

Answer (score 0):

adb shell dumpsys input - this will show the list of all event nodes with the details that you are looking for

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While your answer would be helpful in a one-off situation during development, the question specifically asked for a C function, which points to an intention to find the proper event at runtime.